# Short Int convert to Hex Value

Tags: c#

I have the following code that produces the wrong result.  The writeline hex string is 9BFF where the correct value is FF9B.  What did I do wrong?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        short s = -101;
        short x = unchecked((Int16)0xff9B);
        string hex = Convert.ToHexString(BitConverter.GetBytes(s));
        Console.WriteLine(hex);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt16(hex,16));
        
    }
}
```

result:

```
9BFF
-101
-25601
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("X"));`. Alternatively, if you actually need the bytes in big-endian order regardless of the platform's endianness, use `BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt16BigEndian`.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with `ToString` with the `"X"` or `"x"` (hexadecimal format specifier):

```
public static void Main()
{
    short intValue = -101;
    string hex = intValue.ToString("X");
    
    Console.WriteLine(hex);
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/370tdl)